# How to check if a series of values is in a vector with a for loop. R

Tags: r

I want to categorize values based on whether they're in a vector. I've tried what seems like every which way and it's continuing to not work.

```
orig_vector <- c(0.00632, 0.02731, 0.02729, 0.03237, 0.06905, 0.02985, 0.08829, 0.14455, 0.21124, 0.17004)

cat_vector  <- c(0.00632, 0.02731, 0.02729, 0.03237)

for(j in 1:length(orig_vector)){
  ifelse(orig_vector[j] %in% cat_vector[1:2], orig_vector[j] <- 'Extreme',
         ifelse(orig_vector[j] %in% cat_vector[3:length(cat_vector)], orig_vector[j] <- 'Reasonable',
                orig_vector[j] <- 'Non-Outlier'))
  }         
}
```

I'd like the output to be

```
c("Extreme", "Extreme", "Reasonable", "Reasonable", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier")
```

The challenge is that this function just returns

```
c("Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier", "Non-Outlier")
```

I'm having trouble catching the values with my filter, I'm not sure how else to compare whether a value is equal to one of the values in a vector.

Comment: You question is hard to understand. Give some sample data that we can try at out end, post the expected output.

Comment: there we go, I tried to make it more clear YOLO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` here:

```
output <- sapply(orig_vector, function(x){

    if(x %in% cat_vector[1:2]) return('Extreme')

    else if (x %in% cat_vector[3:length(cat_vector)]) return('Reasonable')

    else return('Non-Outlier')
})

print(output)

 [1] "Extreme"     "Extreme"     "Reasonable"  "Reasonable"  "Non-Outlier" "Non-Outlier"
 [7] "Non-Outlier" "Non-Outlier" "Non-Outlier" "Non-Outlier"
```

Comment: This leads to the function being applied to the whole vector, orig_vector. Is it possible to get the function to apply to one element at a time?

Comment: @Sebastian why is that a problem ? The output matches like you expected.

Comment: It serves this error - if (x %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Aha! In my use case, orig_vector is stored as a dataframe. Fixed! Now it's working, thanks @YOLO